# How to check RadTabControl's SelectedIndex null or not in WPF

Tags: wpf, rad-controls

I have the following function:

```
private void UserDetailTabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, RadSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{                        
    RadTabControl obj = sender as RadTabControl;

    if (obj.SelectedIndex != null)
```

But obj.SelectedIndex != null is giving me warning.
The result of the expression is always 'true' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'

So how to solve this warning?

Comment: K T - why have you accepted only 4 answers for you 16 questions? And why do you ignore any comments?

Answer (score 1):

Why you need to check the **SelectedIndex** for, why not **SelectedItem?** To answer your question, SelectedIndex is of type **int** so the default value of SelectedIndex for TabControl should be -1/0 depending on the control that you are using. Thus, you cannot do

`obj.SelectedIndex != null`,

you can do

```
obj.SelectedIndex < 0
```

for check.